# What does obs confidence interval in statsmodels linear regression in Python

Tags: python

Once you run the regression model with the module 'statsmodels' in Python, you can get the prediction with these confidence intervals:
mean_ci_lower   mean_ci_upper   obs_ci_lower    obs_ci_upper

I know what mean_ci means but I have no idea what obs stands for.

Answer (score 6):

`obs_ci` is the prediction interval, i.e. a confidence interval for a new observation.

It combines the uncertainty about the mean estimate with the randomness of a new observation for given mean. It assumes that residuals are distributed close to normal distribution, uses either normal or t distribution for the prediction interval and is therefore only approximate.

Comment: Thanks! One more quick question! what is difference between mean_ci and obs_ci?

Comment: `mean_ci` is the confidence interval for the expected value or mean `x * beta_hat` given the standard errors of the parameter estimates, i.e. essentially a confidence interval for the regression line. `obs_ci` is essentially a confidence interval for ``x * beta_hat + error`.

Comment: Oh, I got it, Thanks!